# Same function, different code - refactoring mess

Tags: php, namespaces, refactoring

I'm trying to learn by disassembling existing constructs,
my very ambitious attempt is to refactor some code,
first step - change all function names to easily readable format, to see what is going one.

In this process i found far apart:

- `function folder_items()`
- `function getFiles()`

After cleaning their names i found them quite similar in function.
Are they?

=========================================

```
function pszt_files_count($folder) {
    $files = array ();
    if ( $handle = opendir ( $folder ) ) {
        while ( false !== ( $file = readdir ( $handle ) ) ) {
            if ( $file != "." && $file != ".." ) {
                $files [] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return count($files);
}
```

==========================================

```
function pszt_files_arr($path) {
    $handle = opendir($path) or die("pszt_files_arr: Unable to open $path");
    $files_arr = array();
    while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            $files_arr[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    return $files_arr;
}
```

Comment: Looks like it. You could probably replace the first method body with just `return count($pszt_files_arr)`.

Comment: They are doing almost the same, except for the return argument. The first gives the count, the second all files as an array.

Answer (score 0):

they are the same,

you can use one inside the other

first one could be: getFiles($path) {...}

the second could be getFilesCount($path) { return getFiles($path) ; }